# Not able to access the admin panel in zend frame work?

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am working on and android shopping app using zend framework2 and the site is hosted in godaddy.

When i am accessing my index.php (http://mytomatoapp.com/tomato_webservice/admin/public/index.php)  page i am getting the below error.

```
A 404 error occurred
Page not found.
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
No Exception available
```

And also when i am accessing my admin panel (http://admin.mytomatoapp.com/adminpanel/auth/login) i am getting the below error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /adminpanel/auth/login was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I have created a subdomain(admin.mytomatoapp.com) with path public_html/admin and my .htaccess file in public_html/tomato_webservice/admin location is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.mytomatoapp\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.admin\.mytomatoapp\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mytomatoapp\.com\/admin" [R=301,L]
```

and .htaccess in the location (public_html/tomato_webservice/admin/public) is

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

can anyone identify the issue and help me, i was stuck at this for few days.